# How to auto join a domain with a password prompt or encrypted password?

Tags: xml, powershell, batch-file, encryption

I know this is possible but I don't know the syntax.

I would like to create a script to auto join a domain i.e create the machine account and join the domain.

Security is a concern so I would like to be either prompted for credentials or have them somehow encrypted in the script.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In PowerShell you can also use the `Add-Computer` command e.g.:

```
Add-Computer -DomainName Acme -Credential (Get-Credential domain\username)
```

That will prompt you to enter the password for the specified user. This command can be used to add the local computer to a domain or workgroup. And as the docs note:

> It also creates a domain account if the computer is added to the
>   domain without an account.
>
> You can use the parameters of this cmdlet to specify an organizational unit 
>   (OU) and domain controller or to perform an unsecure join.

If you want to save the password in an encrypted form, that gets trickier is as usual when security is a real concern.

One way to encrypt & save the password is to use `Read-Host -AsSecureString` and export that as binary e.g.:

```
# Prepare the encrypted password:
30> $ss = Read-Host -AsSecureString
***********
33> $key = [byte[]](0..15)
34> $encpasswd = ConvertFrom-SecureString -Key $key -SecureString $ss
35> $encpasswd
76492d1116743f0423413b16050a5345MgB8AEMAbQBSAEIAMwA4AG4AMABKAHEAMAAvACsAUgAzACsAWQBNADgAZwBiAHcAPQA9AHwAOABkAGYAMAA4AGY
AMQA5ADQAYQA5ADAAMQAzADAANwBlADUANwBiADcANwBmADEAOABkAGMAZgA2AGYANgBiAGUAZQBlAGIANgA1AGUAZABmADIAOABhADkAZQA4AGUAMgBkAG
YAOAAwAGMAOQAwAGEAZAAzAGQAYQBjAGMAZQA=

36> $encpasswd > encp.txt
```

Now you have an encrypted password in the file but here's the rub, you pushed the shared secret from the password itself to the key.  So the key should be protected just as the password would be but unfortunately you have to have the key to decrypt e.g.:

```
39> $encpasswd = Get-Content encp.txt
40> $ss = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $encpasswd -Key $key
41> $cred = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 'Acme\Joe',$ss
42> Add-Computer -DomainName Acme -Credential $cred
```

Note that the `Key` can be any 16, 24 or 32 byte array.

Answer (score 2):

I can remember doing this once a while back when I administered a Windows Domain but I'm a bit rusty now that I administer just Unix networks, but you should only need the following.

```
netdom join {Workstation Name} /domain:{Windows Domain} /userd:{Domain Admin} /password:*
```

As far as the password goes, I'm not aware of any way to encrypt the password within a script. But specifying a wildcard as the password instructs the command to prompt for the password.

Here is the documentation for NetDom: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788049.aspx

Comment: Will that create the computer account in active directory as well as join the computer to the domain?
The wildcard and prompt for password works better for me so thanks for the tip.

Comment: I did not do Windows Domains for quite long enough to understand all it's terminology but if I'm not mistaking, ain't a computer account created if one is not present? I've never had to manually create them before.